# Adding .so and symlink to .so in Yocto

Tags: shared-libraries, yocto, bitbake

I want to have multiple versions of library mylib and symlink that points to latest one. So, there would be latest library in `/usr/lib/mylib/mylib.so.0.5` and symlink `/usr/lib/mylib/mylib.so -> /usr/lib/mylib/mylib.so.0.5`.

My recipe can currently work without adding symlink

My Yocto recipe is working nicely when I remove following line:

`lnr ${D}${libdir}/mylibrary/mylib.so.${MY_LIB_VER} ${D}${libdir}/mylibrary/mylib.so`

```
FILES_{PN}-dev += "${D}${libdir}/mylib/mylib.so.${MYLIB_VER}"
FILES_{PN}-dev += "${D}${libdir}/mylib/mylib.so"
```

Error that prevents me from building:
`QA Issue: non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of adding .so files to FILES_{PN}-dev

```
FILES_{PN}-dev += "${D}${libdir}/mylib/mylib.so.${MYLIB_VER}"
FILES_{PN}-dev += "${D}${libdir}/mylib/mylib.so"
```

I've added it to FILES_SOLIBSDEV

```
FILES_SOLIBSDEV += "${D}${libdir}/mylib/mylib.so.${MYLIB_VER}"
FILES_SOLIBSDEV += "${D}${libdir}/mylib/mylib.so"
```

and now everything is building and package on which this package depends on sees it as available. I haven't fully built that other package, but packagesare available in `build/tmp/sysroots-components` folder.